# how to close an element when click outside?

Tags: jquery, html

when i click on the button, the button toggle a specific class and opens something, this works,
but the problem when i tried to type a code that will close that object when i click outside it, it doesn't work

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    $('.list').toggle();
    $('button').toggleClass('something');
  });
  $(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target !== 'list, button') {
      $('.list').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.list {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  background: lightgray;
  display: none;
}

button {
  background: green
}

.something {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='list'></div>
<button>button</button>
```

Comment: if (e.target !== 'list, button') { <-- not right target will never equal that string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code , here you will open the list and move over it but when you click outside of button and list , the list will be hidden :

```js
var change ="y";

$('button').on('click', function() {
   if(change == "y") { $(".list").show(); }});

$('button').on('blur', function() {
    if(change == "x") { $(".list").hide();
    change="y";}});
  
      
$('.list').on('mouseover', function() { change="y";});
$('.list').on('mouseout', function() {change="x";
$('button').focus();});
```

```css
.list {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  background: lightgray;
  display: none;
}

button {
  background: green
}

.something {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='list'></div>
<button>button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have a CSS declaration of `display: none`. You'll also  probably want to add some content to `.list` (so it can be hidden), as is done in the following example:

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target !== 'list, button') {
      $('.list').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.list {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='list'>List</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Yes thanks, but this isn't what i wanted, i wanted to do what you did but when the button exists, do you understand me? 
to make the button opens the list normally  and in case i click outside it, it's closed,